# how to pick a image file from sdcard and then how to send it to the server?

Tags: android, android-camera

---

//below

In my application i have a button **select image from sdcard** and on clicking it, I want to explore all the images then user will select any image after this the selected image file will be uploaded to server.

And also i have an another button **from camera** on clicking it, first i want to take a snapshot, and then uploaded to server, please tell me any way by  example??

Comment: [Please do some research before posting a question](http://www.google.com.pk/search?q=android+how+to+upload+picture+to+server)

Comment: @ravi-I somehow tried to edit your question but it still remains as a MYSTERY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it is very easy to browse the image by deafult gallery using the
>   intent so by using the intent you can easily choose the image  from sd
>   card and from your file browser.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I use to query the phone's MediaStore and return a cursor object containing all images. After that you may upload them to your server, but I suggest you take care of this first part in an AsyncTask.

```
class LoadImagesFromSDCard extends AsyncTask<Object, LoadedImage, Object> {

   //Load images from SDCARD and display
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        //setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true); 
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        Bitmap newBitmap = null;
        Uri uri = null;            

        // Set up an array of the Thumbnail Image ID column we want
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID};
        // Create the cursor pointing to the SDCard
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery( MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                projection, // Which columns to return
                null,       // Return all rows
                null,       
                null); 
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);
        int size = cursor.getCount();
        // If size is 0, there are no images on the SD Card.
        if (size == 0) {
            //No Images available, post some message to the user
        }
        int imageID = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            cursor.moveToPosition(i);
            imageID = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
            uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + imageID);
            try {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri));
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    newBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 70, 70, true);
                    bitmap.recycle();
                    if (newBitmap != null) {
                        publishProgress(new LoadedImage(newBitmap));
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //Error fetching image, try to recover
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
        return null;
    }
```